# How to execute update join query?

Tags: mysql

How do we run these types of queries in MySQL?

How to execute these types of queries how we run in MySQL, i.e. update join query?

```
UPDATE file_master t1,users t2 SET
    t1.Status = "cancel", 
    t1.is_credit_revers=1, 
    t1.is_credit_reversed=1,
    t1.t_reversal=t1.credit,
    t2.credit=t1.credit+
     (
       select sum(t1.credit) from file_master where FileID in(7,6,5)
     )
WHERE t1.FileID in(7,6,5) 
and t1.CRN=t2.id 
and t1.CRN=1 ;
```

> 1093 - Table 't1' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Answer (score 1):

MySQL objects to updating a table which is also in a sub query

You can sometimes hide the sub query within another sub query to get around this.

As such try something like this:-

```
UPDATE file_master t1
INNER JOIN users t2 
ON t1.CRN = t2.id 
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT credit_sum
    FROM
    (
        SELECT SUM(credit) AS credit_sum 
        FROM file_master 
        WHERE FileID IN(7,6,5)
    ) t3
) t4
SET t1.Status = "cancel", 
t1.is_credit_revers = 1, 
t1.is_credit_reversed = 1,
t1.t_reversal = t1.credit,
t2.credit = t1.credit + t4.credit_sum
WHERE t1.FileID in(7,6,5) 
AND t1.CRN = 1 ;
```